# C++ how to use "operator new" keyword instead of C malloc()?

Tags: c++, data-structures

```c
StackMeta_t *mystack_create(size_t objsize)
{
  StackMeta_t *elem;
  elem = (StackMeta_t*)malloc(sizeof(StackMeta_t));
    if(elem == NULL)
    {
      return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      elem->stack = NULL; // my actual stack basically the first elem(the top)
      elem->objsize = objsize;  // size of the datatype
      elem->numelem = 0;        // total count of elem inside the stack
    }
    return elem;
}

//PUSH
int mystack_push(StackMeta_t *data_stack, void* obj)
{
    if(data_stack == NULL)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    
    StackObject_t *nodeObject = NULL;
    nodeObject = (StackObject_t*)malloc(sizeof(StackObject_t));
    if(nodeObject == NULL)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    
    nodeObject->obj = malloc(data_stack->objsize);
    if(data_stack->stack == NULL)
    {
      nodeObject->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      nodeObject->next = data_stack->stack;   
    }
    memcpy(nodeObject->obj, obj, data_stack->objsize);
    data_stack->stack = nodeObject;
    data_stack->numelem++;

    return 0;
}
```

So I am trying to translate my C code into C++ code. These are Linked List and Stacks data structure

I researched that the malloc() version of C++ is the `new` keyword. So creating memory for the
linked list `nodeObject`, I did `StackObject_t *nodeObject = new StackObject_t;`.

But the problem I encountered is creating memory for the `obj` of the Linked List. The data type for this variable is `void* obj;`. So that would be using a pointer to the `objsize` created with by the `mystack_create(size_t objsize)` function.

My question is, how do I convert `nodeObject->obj = malloc(data_stack->objsize);` to C++ while using the `new` keyword?

I tried doing `nodeObject->obj = new data_stack->objsize;` and the error gives me `expected a type specifier`. Do I need to cast `data_stack->objsize`? and what is the syntax for this for future reference? I have been coding with C for almost a year now and I know a few OOP from C#. Now I am just beginning to learn C++ and I couldn't find any answer for this type of situation.

Comment: The common syntax is:  `Object * pointer_to_object = new Object;`.

Comment: C and C++ are two completely different languages. Translating from C to C++, one statement at a time, always ends in tears. The only way to learn C++, that's required in order to understand C++ and figure out how to correctly translate from C to C++, is [with a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not a replacement for a C++ textbook, and C++ is too complicated to be learned by asking one question at a time; a C++ textbook is required.

Comment: also, just use std::stack, and don't use memset

Comment: post the original `C` code and the actual `C++` stuff as it is now. And translate the data structure not the program in the first place. (I believe you know that STL provides this and more data strucutres, called __contianers__ in ``C++` and you can replicate that

Comment: When allocating more than one instance, use `std::vector`.  Syntax:  `std::vector<Object> database;`.

Comment: Even though your question involves C, it is not about C, and tagging it with C is not very helpful—people who are following the C tag but are not interested in the C++ tag might not be able to help much, and people in the future using the C tag to search for questions about C issues will not be helped by finding this one. So I am removing the C tag.

Comment: Back around 2008 I figured that a C++ course I took in the mid'90s and 20 years of Java and C meant I knew C++. Holy <expletive deleted> was I wrong. I am still finding, cringing over, and replacing as quietly as possible code I wrote between 2008 and 2012. [Get a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You know C, so you won't have to start with one of the See Spot Code variety, but I cannot stress enough: Get a good book. Then read through some of the Scott Meyers *Effective * books to fill in the blanks.

Comment: *So I am trying to translate my C code into C++ code.* -- *These are Linked List* -- `std::list` -- *and Stacks* -- `std::stack`.  Work with those.  Not only will your code have less bugs, you get to actually learn how this is done in C++.  Also, I am assuming you know how to write a stack and linked list class already, so why waste time doing it all over again form scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not use `void*` in C++ - it's usually not a good idea to abandon the type system. Instead, use [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).

So instead of doing

```
struct StackMeta_t
{
   //stuff
   void* obj;
};
```

just do

```
template <class T>
struct StackMeta_t
{
   //stuff
   T* obj;
};
```

Whatever type you put as `T` is what controls the typing of `obj`; for example, `StackMeta_t<int>` would result in `int* obj;`, etc, unless you'd rather change the typing of `obj` halfway through your program, which is probably something you would not want to do anyways.

Also just use `std::stack` if you want to use a stack in C++.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to use C++ instead of the old C methods, then you should go all the way and use the current guidelines. The current way to use pointers and memory management is through [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers).

The reason these are useful, especially for your case, is because they do both the memory management for you (allocation and de-allocation) and prevent memory leaks or "read-after-free" kind of bugs.

I did a simple implementation of your stack object using `std::shared_ptr`, which is appropriate in your case as you want to reference an external object in your `obj*` member.

```cpp
struct StackObject
{
    StackObject(void* p_obj)
    {
        obj = p_obj;
    }
    void* obj;
    std::shared_ptr<StackObject> next;
};

struct StackMeta
{
    int numelem;
    size_t objsize;
    std::shared_ptr<StackObject> stack; // First object

    StackMeta(size_t p_objsize)
    {
        objsize = p_objsize;
        stack = nullptr;
        numelem = 0;
    }

    void push(void* obj)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<StackObject> newobj = std::make_shared<StackObject>(obj);
        newobj->next = stack;
        stack = newobj; // make the stack reference the newly created object
        numelem++;
    }
};
```

For this to function, you need to include `memory`.
To test this, I made a simple `main()`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    StackMeta list(4); // 4 bytes for integers

    int some_int1 = 48;
    int some_int2 = 480;
    int some_int3 = 148;
    int some_int4 = 408;

    list.push(&some_int1);
    list.push(&some_int2);
    list.push(&some_int3);
    list.push(&some_int4);

    StackObject* curr_obj_ptr = list.stack.get();
    while(curr_obj_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        int curr_obj = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(curr_obj_ptr->obj));
        std::cout << "Current object: " << curr_obj << std::endl;
        curr_obj_ptr = curr_obj_ptr->next.get();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```
Current object: 408
Current object: 148
Current object: 480
Current object: 48
```

Please correct me if I misunderstood your implementation.

A final note: It is a very bad practice to use `void*` in C++. In our case, it forced us to call a `reinterpret_cast` which is not desirable. The correct approach is to use a template for the `StackMeta` and `StackObject` classes.

Comment: In case you're interested, here's an implementation of the `pop` function:
```c

void* pop(){void* obj = stack->obj;stack = stack->next;numelem--;return obj;}

```